# How to connect fragment list Activity with Button click Main Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.title = (String) getTitle();
    // Getting reference to the DrawerLayout
    this.drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    this.drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

    this.fragments[0] = new My_Main_Fragment(this);
    this.fragments[1] = new My_Breakfast_Fragment();
    this.fragments[2] = new My_Lunch_Fragment();
    this.fragments[3] = new My_Dinner_Fragment();
    this.fragments[4] = new My_Dessert_Fragment();
    this.fragments[5] = new My_Seat_Plan_Fragment();
    this.fragments[6] = new My_Beverages_Fragment();

    this.item_titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);
```

.................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
public class My_Seat_Plan_Fragment extends Activity{
```

Button create, edit, view, delet, find;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.air_main_interface);

    create = (Button)findViewById(R.id.note_add);
    edit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.note_edit);
    view = (Button)findViewById(R.id.note_view);
    delet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.note_delete);
    find = (Button)findViewById(R.id.note_find);

    create.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent in = new Intent(My_Seat_Plan_Fragment.this,Seat_create.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

................................................................................................

In below attached two classes i need to connect the Main Activity with the fragment class... 
Main Activity is followed as extends Activity implements My_Fragments_Parent {

and Fragment Activity is as followed as public class My_Seat_Plan_Fragment extends Activity{

but im getting an error in the main activity in the line

this.fragments[5] = new My_Seat_Plan_Fragment();   ------ saying cannot convert from My Seat_Plan_Fragment to Fragment

So if I change My seat_Plan Fragment Extends Activity then button activities cannot be done...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you can use something like this in your fragment:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).someMethod();
```